# How can I share modules between the client and server using node.js if my module depends on another?

Tags: javascript, oop, node.js

Here's my Node.js situation:

I'm trying to share code between my Node.js server and the browser for a game.  Basically, I want to share the game logic.

Lets say my game has a Table, and that Table can have Players.  I want each of these to be modules that can be used by both the client and server.

I know I can do something like this:

```
(function(exports){

   exports.test = function(){
        return 'hello world'
    };

})(typeof exports === 'undefined'? this['Table']={}: exports);
```

And I can get something like this working with my Table. However, what if I need to use Players inside this Table module?  Something like:

```
(function(exports){

   exports.test = function(){
        var Player = require('./Player');
        var p1 = new Player();
    };

})(typeof exports === 'undefined'? this['Table']={}: exports);
```

While this would work in Node, it obviously wont in on the browser, since require is not defined.  And without require, it would work on the browser, but not Node.

**TL;DR**: I need to "include" code from one module in another module, which can be shared by both the browser (client) and server.

Thanks

Comment: +25 for `TL;DR` section.

Comment: https://github.com/component/component

Answer (score -1):

You could use require.js to load modules in both node and the browser.

[See documentation on the require.js page](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/node.html)

Comment: This doesn't address how to resolve requiring a  common module that needs to depend on different submodules depending on what environment it's running in.